# Probability of a rectangular card intersecting the lines of a floor

Tags: probability

I have attempted this problem, but do not understand how the answer was achieved. The question is as follows (coming from Henk Tijms 'Understanding Probability' (3rd edn.) book):

> **Problem 7.16**
>
> Consider the following variant of Buffon's needle problem. A rectangular card with the side lengths $a$ and $b$ is
>   dropped at random on the floor. It is assumed that the length
>   $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ of the diagonal of the card is smaller than the
>   distance $D$ between the parallel lines on the floor. Show that the
>   probability of the card intersecting one of the lines is given by
>   $\frac{2(a+b)}{\pi D}$.

I have let $y$ to be the centre of the rectangular card to the closest line of the two, and $x$ be the angle of the diagonal of the card. Thus I have defined the sample space to be $\Omega = \{(x,y): 0 \leq x \leq \pi, 0 \leq y \leq \frac{1}{2}D\}$.

The hypotenuse from the middle of the card to the closest line is then $\frac{y}{\sin(x)}$. If $\frac{y}{\sin(x)} > \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ then the card does not touch either of the two lines. So if $\frac{y}{\sin(x)} \leq \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ then the card intersects a line of the floor. Thus $y \leq \frac{\sin(x)}{2}\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, and so calculating the probability that the card intersects one of the lines is:

$\begin{align} \frac{\int _{0} ^{\pi} {\frac{\sin(x)}{2}\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\;dx}{\frac{1}{2}\pi D} &= \frac{\int _{0} ^{\pi} {\sin(x)\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\;dx}{\pi D} \\ &= \frac{2\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}{\pi D} \end{align}$

I'm not sure if I skipped something or made some error here, but thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the range of integration for $x$. Assume WLOG that $a\leq b$. There being two diagonals and thus two choices for $x$, we want $x$ to be the angle between a diagonal and the parallel lines that is closest to a right-angle. Then we have $\theta\leq x\leq \theta+\pi/2$ where $\theta$ is the angle between either diagonal and the long side of the rectangle. When the long side of the rectangle is parallel with the parallel lines, $x=\theta$; when the long side is perpendicular to the parallel lines, $x=\theta+\pi/2.$

It's easy to calculate $\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(a/b\right)$.

So the sample space is 
$$\Omega = \left\{(x,y)\;:\; \theta\lt x\lt \theta+\frac{\pi}{2},\; 0\lt y\lt \frac{D}{2} \right\}.$$

Now, $x,y$ are independent and uniformly distributed over their range so their density functions are:

$$f_X(x) = \dfrac{2}{\pi} \\ f_Y(y) = \dfrac{2}{D}.$$

And as you found, the region where the card intersects a line satisfies

$$y \lt \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin{x}.$$

So for the required probability, we integrate as follows

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(\text{intersection}) &=& \int_{x=\theta}^{\theta+\pi/2} \dfrac{2}{\pi} \int_{y=0}^{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin{x}} \dfrac{2}{D}\;dydx \\
&=& \int_{x=\theta}^{\theta+\pi/2} \dfrac{2}{\pi D} \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin{x} \;dx \\
&=& \dfrac{2}{\pi D} \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\;\bigg[-\cos{x} \bigg]_{\theta}^{\theta+\pi/2} \\
&=& \dfrac{2}{\pi D} \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\;\left(\cos{\theta} + \sin{\theta} \right) \qquad\qquad\text{(using basic trig identities)} \\
&=& \dfrac{2}{\pi D} \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\;\left(\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} + \dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \right) \\
&=& \dfrac{2(a+b)}{\pi D}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Since there are two diagonals to choose, would we also count when the card goes from $\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\theta + \pi$ (where the closest diagonal line is the other one?)? I imagine going from $\theta$ to $\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}$ only captures the first half of the card rotation where it hits the floor's line.

Comment: Hi @user246678 You don't have to because it's completely symmetrical. Where the second diagonal takes over, it's a mirror image of the $\theta$ to $\theta+\pi/2$ range. Still, you could use that full range if you want and you should get the same result. Note the density function for $x$ would then change from $f_X(x)=2/\pi$ to $f_X(x)=1/\pi$.

Comment: @user246678 Correction to my last comment. The extension of the range for $x$ would be as follows. Range $\theta\leq x\leq\pi-\theta$. One diagonal is "active" for $\theta\leq x\leq\pi/2+\theta$ and the other active for $\pi/2-\theta\leq x\leq\pi-\theta$. These ranges overlap. So $x$ no longer uniform: instead $f_X(x)=1/\pi$ for $\theta\leq x\leq\pi/2-\theta$ and $\pi/2+\theta\leq x\leq\pi-\theta$; $f_X(x)=2/\pi$ for $\pi/2-\theta\leq x\leq\pi/2+\theta$. So the integral is in 3 parts as follows but you can see, this method adds complexity (continued next comment)

Comment: @user246678 The integral is: $\int_{x=\theta}^{\pi/2-\theta}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{y=0}^{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin{x}} \frac{2}{D}\;dydx + \int_{x=\pi/2-\theta}^{\pi/2+\theta}\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{y=0}^{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin{x}} \frac{2}{D}\;dydx + \int_{x=\pi/2+\theta}^{\pi-\theta}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{y=0}^{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin{x}} \frac{2}{D}\;dydx$.

Answer (score 2):

Using black magic :)

We have either two intersections of the perimeter, either zero, so $E($number of border crossings$)=2P($card intersects lines$)$, hence $P($card intersects lines$)=0.5E($number of border crossings$)$.

$E($border crossings$)$ is proportional to the length of the perimeter, so it has the form $k\times (2a+2b)$. But for circle with diameter $D$ the $E($border crossings$)$ is equal to 2. So $2=k\times \pi D$, and $k=\frac{2}{\pi D}$.

Hence, $P($card intersects lines$)=0.5\times \frac{2}{\pi D} \times (2a+2b)=\frac{2a+2b}{\pi D}$.

Comment: +1. But you should explain the line "P(card intersects lines)=0.5E(number of border crossings)."

Comment: Updated the answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am unsure about the idea of this approach. Could you give some further explanation as to what you did (sorry if I have no idea what this nice black magic is) :)